# Autobahn-JS doesn't receive subscription for publish on same page (sample)

Tags: javascript, websocket, autobahn, crossbar, autobahnjs

I have a crossbar.io server setup and I am trying the example code in a browser (chrome 81.x) on https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js

```
    // 1) subscribe to a topic
   function onevent(args) {
      console.log("Event:", args[0]);
   }
   session.subscribe('com.myapp.hello', onevent);

   // 2) publish an event
   session.publish('com.myapp.hello', ['Hello, world!']);
```

I don't see the subscribe message.  I have since developed my own application and I see the same thing.  A web page that publishes the event doesn't have it's subscribe called.  In other words, if I have the same page open in 2 windows and have page A publish a message, page B gets the subscribe event, but page A does not.

Not sure if this is an issue with autobahn-js or with crossbar.io.

I previously had a WAMP v1 implementation (with a custom router) that supported this.  It's kind of critical for me to make sure a page sees its own publish messages.  There is a lot of work for me to convert my code if this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  It's in the documentation depending on which version Google finds for you.

https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/blob/master/doc/programming.md

> By default, a publisher will not receive an event it publishes even when the publisher is itself subscribed to the topic subscribed to. This behavior can be overridden by passing exclude_me: False in the options.

```
session.publish('com.myapp.complex', [1, 2, 3], {foo: "bar"}, {exclude_me: false});
```